# Example of certain polynomial over field

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

Construct a simple polynomial $f(x)$ of degree bigger than $1$ that has coefficients in some field $k$ and is irreducible over $k$, but is neither separable nor purely inseparable over $k$.

**My approach:**

Consider a polynomial $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)+1\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.
Using rational root test we can show that it has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$ and hence is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since $p(x)=x^3-6x^2+7x-5$ then $p'(x)=3x^2-12x+7$ and we can check that $\text{gcd}(p,p')\neq 1$ because long-division shows that $p=p'\times(\frac{x}{3}-\frac{2}{3})+(-\frac{10x}{3}-\frac{1}{3})$. Hence $p(x)$ is not separable.

Also $p(x)$ is not purely inseperable. Otherwise $p(x)=(x-\beta)^3$ but comparing coefficients and expansion will give us a contradiction.

**Question:** Can anyone give another example in finite fields? I was trying to construct such example in finite fields but was not able to do it.

Comment: Irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ have simple roots, because $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x] \implies \frac{f}{gcd(f,f')} \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. In fields of characteristic $p$ it may fail because it may happen that $f' = 0$ for $f$ non-constant, for example $f(x)=x^p- t^p \in \mathbb{F}_p(t^p)[x]$ is irreducible and $f'= p x^{p-1}= 0$

Comment: @reuns, is my example corect?

Comment: No, your example is not correct. Every irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, or indeed any field of characteristic zero, is separable.

Comment: @jmerry, but what is wrong with my reasoning? Could you show it explicitly?

Comment: Is $(x^2+1)^2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ irreducible ?

Comment: @reuns, certainly not! It has already factorization

Comment: What's wrong with your reasoning? The GCD of those two polynomials is $1$. The Euclidean algorithm has multiple steps; you don't stop at the first remainder, but instead keep going until you get a zero.

Comment: Does it have any root in $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: @jmerry, could give more details in an answer where my long division is not correct?

Comment: @reuns, it has not roots in rationals.

Comment: The point reuns and jmerry wanted to make is an analogy to the following. If you divide $a=10$ by $b=6$ you get quotient $q=1$ and remainder $r=4$. Yet, $\gcd(10,6)\neq4$.  By running Euclid to the end you will see that $\gcd(10,6)=2$. You failed to run Euclid to the end, and you have not calculated $\gcd(p(x),p'(x))$ yet.

Comment: And, over a finite field every irreducible polynomial is separable. This is because finite fields are [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, after your last comment I suppose that there is no such example because as you said any irreducible polynomial is separable!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, could you give me some link where I could find this interesting example? I am sure that i cannot solve it by myself

Comment: Let $L=\Bbb{F}_p(t)$, $t$ transcendental over the prime field. Assume that $p\equiv-1\pmod 4$, so that we know that $-1$ has no square root in $\Bbb{F}_p$. Let $K$ be the subfield $\Bbb{F}_p(t^p)\subset L$. I think that
$$f(x)=x^{2p}+t^{p}$$ is irreducible in $K[x]$ (Eisenstein). Its zeros are $\pm i\sqrt{t}$, both of multipicity $p$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I guess it would be better if you give the separate answer. I'll appreciate it!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, What is $i$ here? Complex number $i$? It seems quite weird because there is nothing in common between $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It is just a square root of $-1$. There is such an element in the extension field $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, It makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

[From a discussion in the comments, by request. Not a true answer]

What is the greatest common divisor of $x^3-6x^2+7x-5$ and its derivative $3x^2-12x+7$, over $\mathbb{Q}$?

We run the Euclidean algorithm. Our first step is $p_0(x)=x^3-6x^2+7x-5$, and our second is $p_1(x)=3x^2-12x+7$. For convenience, normalize to a monic polynomial $p_1^*(x)=x^2-4x+\frac73$. Then divide:
$$(x-2)p_1^*(x)=x^3-6x^2+(\tfrac73+8)x-\tfrac{14}{3}$$
$$p_0(x)=(x-2)p_1^*(x)+\left(-\frac{10}{3}x-\frac13\right)$$
That's our next remainder; $p_2(x)=-\frac{10}{3}x-\frac13$, and we normalize to $p_2^*(x)=x+\frac1{10}$. And now, the next step:
$$(x-\tfrac{41}{10})p_2^*(x)=x^2-4x-\tfrac{41}{100}$$
$$p_1^*(x) = (x-\tfrac{41}{10})p_2^*(x) + \left(\frac73+\frac{41}{100}\right)$$
That's our remainder $p_3=\frac{823}{300}$, normalized to $p_3^*=1$. Then, of course, $p_2^*(x)=(x+\frac1{10})p_3^*(x)+0$, and the algorithm terminates.

The GCD is a constant. Since we're working over $\mathbb{Q}$, we might as well normalize that constant to $1$. Your long division wasn't wrong - it was just very incomplete.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I got your point! +1